# LSTM understanding samples, timesteps and features

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, lstm

In the task of implementing an LSTM model for weather prediction across various locations in the USA, the dataset comprises gridded 2D arrays containing nine distinct variables like temperature and pressure. Each hourly snapshot is represented in 100 files, with each file containing data for 2000 points, each point corresponding to a specific geographical location.

My question is, what will be my samples, timestep, features in this case?